# Add sparkline chat at the first or last column in the ag-grid pivot mode

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to add spackline chat at the first or last column in the ag-grid pivot mode.
[for example, data will be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKKQz.png)

this data will be shown in the ag-grid pivot mode.

I want to add custom column at the first (last), and render line chart.

[for example, like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZKUA.png)